# If logic = true, then use previous row's value, otherwise another column

Tags: powerquery

I'm a beginner to Power Query and it seems that some of the syntax has changed so have been trying to look this one up for a while and still no further forward. I need to reference the previous row of data, but it needs to be the same column, not a new one.

I'm pulling out employee data and the employee number is only indicated once every 100 lines or so. I have a column to pull the data out and it displays the employee number. I need to repeat that employee number for every line until there is a new employee number.
I've created an index field. The previous step name is Employee and the column it creates is [Employee].
Adding a new custom column called [EmpNo] and adding the following just results in errors against every field but the ones matching the [Employee] column indicating it doesn't like #"Employee"{[Index]-1}[EmpNo]

```
if [Employee] = "" then #"Employee"{[Index]-1}[EmpNo] else [Employee]
```

Anyone any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
If left cell = "" then use above cell else use left cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should just be right-clicking the [EmpNo] column and using fill ... down...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(Source,{"EmpNo"})
in #"Filled Down"
```

The code you are trying would **NOT WORK** for your problem, since the second blank cell would just pull from the first blank cell above that one.  For reference, that **bad** code would be:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [EmpNo]= null then #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[EmpNo] else [EmpNo])
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: I had tried the fill down previous which didn't work, however if I replace the "" empty cells with nulls the fill down works. Thanks for your help.